# IIS Url Rewrite Returning 404 when pattern matches

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have a web application running on box A. I have a WCF service running on box B.

Box A serves the front web site, whilst Box B holds the WCF service. They are in different security groups within AWS.

The rule for URL Rewrite from my web.config is as follows:

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*ReverseProxy/*"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.0.0.29/service/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
    </rule>
```

If I log onto Box A I can access the service on Box B by going direct. If I go to the web application on Box A and try to hit an address that should activate the URL Rewrite rule. I get a 404 for the service, rather than a result from the service.

I have taken the URL from Chrome's console, and run it through the test in IIS and it definitely matches correctly.

Comment: Which URL are you executing from Box A, which is giving you 404? Is `proxy` enabled in ARR settings?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev I am hitting a html page, which makes a call (AJAX) to the service. So in the case of this it would be sub.domain.tld/index.html which calls to sub.domain.tld/service/params which whilst a request to Box A, should be routed to box B via the URL rewrite proxy options.

Comment: If it calls `sub.domain.tld/service/params ` then it means that it will not match with your regex `*ReverseProxy/*`. Isn't it?

Comment: Should have been clearer. It actually calls:

pReverseProxy/webApi/datastore/72285cc1f-9e1b-43e2-8553-a1a501eb0f71

Comment: It should rewrite it to `http://10.0.0.29/service/webApi/datastore/72285cc1f-9e1b-43e2-8553-a1a5‌​01eb0f71` Is it correct?

Comment: And can you confirm that proxy is enabled in ARR settings?

Comment: It should rewrite to there. ARR has Enable proxy checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158002/discussion-between-victor-leontyev-and-parttimelegend).